# Using Newton's method to find $M$, the unique positive zero of $x^2+x-1$

Tags: limits, recurrence-relations, limits-without-lhopital, recursion, newton-raphson

Using Newton's method to find $M$, the unique positive zero of  $x^2+x-1$. Obtain a recursive formula for the error term $e_n$ use it to prove $a_n \rightarrow M$

Recursive formula for $a_n:\quad$ $a_{n+1} = a_n - \frac{a_n^2+a_n-1}{2a_n + 1} = \frac{2a_n^2 + a_n - a_n^2-a_n+1}{2a_n+1}= \frac{a_n^2+1}{2a_n+1}$

Recursive formula for $e_n:\quad$ $e_{n+1} = \frac{(e_n+M)^2+1}{2(e_n+M)+1}$

To show that $a_n \rightarrow M$, it is sufficient to show that for every $\epsilon > 0$ holds $|e_n| < \epsilon$.
How should I do that?

Comment: @user376343 The one in the body is the right one. I made the changes.

Comment: Are you sure your simplification of $a_{n+1}$ is correct? It looks like you've got a vanishing $a_n^2$ in your last equality.

Comment: @Jam Thank you.

Comment: Please recheck the numerator of formula of $a_{n+1}$ you are getting. A one should be added I think.

Comment: Also an $M$ should be subtracted from the RHS of the last term since $e_{n+1}$ is error term.

Comment: @Martund One more mistake thank you. About substracting I think I am right because $a_n = e_n + M$

Comment: Yes, therefore, $a_{n+1}=e_{n+1}+M$

Comment: Ah... you mean there )) Yeah you are right